# JNI/C socket connection error on Solaris 11

Tags: sockets, java-native-interface, solaris

Our application uses several socket connections (to localhost) implemented in c, with one connection using a jni/c socket connection. All of them call the same include to open the socket, and all are successful when we run the application on Solaris 10. 
Migrating to Solaris 11, we are finding that only the socket connections built in c are working, the one jni/c connection will not. I've added output to see what exactly is being sent to the connect call and it looks like the call is getting everything it needs:

```
"sock_connect: socket status: 0, sock_d: 27, serv_addr: ***.***.***.***, sizeof: 16"

So for the call below, sock_d = 27
                       serv_addr = (it returns a good IP, but my PM said he'd kill me if I put the actual IP) 
                       sizeof(serv_addr) = 16
which should be all the parameters connect() needs in the code snippet below.

.
.
.
.
status = connect(sock_d, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

if (status < 0){
   fprintf(stderr, "sock_connect 4: after connect errno: %i, error %sn", errno, strerror(errno));
   if (errno == EINPROGRESS){
      fprintf(stderr, "sock_connect, errno == EINPROGRESS\n");
.
.
.
```

Truss output for the failed connection seems to indicate an `EINPROGRESS` error. Our code is supposed to validate for this possibility, but it does not trigger an if statement that checks to see if the `error == EINPROGRESS`. It never reaches the second `fprintf` statement. We have disabled IPv6 on the server, as we thought perhaps java was trying to force this protocol, but this didn't make a difference either.

The exact same libraries and executables will work on both servers, right up until the jni socket call is made. From that point on Solaris 10 keeps going but Solaris 11 will not.

Has anyone seen this before? Please let me know what else you need to see and I'll post it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This code incorrectly assumes `fprintf()` will never modify `errno`:

```
if (status < 0){
   fprintf(stderr, "sock_connect 4: after connect errno: %i, error %sn", errno, strerror(errno));
   if (errno == EINPROGRESS){
      fprintf(stderr, "sock_connect, errno == EINPROGRESS\n");
```

The [POSIX standard for `errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) states (emphasis mine):

> The value of `errno` **shall be defined only after a call to a function for which it is explicitly stated to be set and until it is changed by the next function call** or if the application assigns it a value.

And per the [Solaris 11.3 `fprintf()` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54766/fprintf-3c.html#scrolltoc), `fprintf()` can set `errno`:

**Errors**

> For the conditions under which `printf()`, `fprintf()`, and
>   `dprintf()` will fail and may fail, refer to fputc(3C) or fputwc(3C).
>
> The `snprintf()` function will fail if:
>
> **EOVERFLOW**
>
> The value of n is greater than INT_MAX or the number of bytes needed
>   to hold the output excluding the terminating null is greater than
>   INT_MAX.
>
> All forms of `printf()` will fail if:
>
> **EILSEQ**
>
> A wide-character code that does not correspond to a valid character
>   has been detected.
>
> **EINVAL**
>
> There are insufficient arguments.
>
> The `dprintf()` function will fail if:
>
> **EBADF**
>
> The `fildes` argument is not a valid file descriptor.
>
> The `printf()`, `fprintf()`, `dprintf()`, and `asprintf()` functions
>   may fail due to an underlying `malloc(3C)` failure if:
>
> **EAGAIN**
>
> Storage space is temporarily unavailable.
>
> **ENOMEM**
>
> Insufficient storage space is available.

Comment: Ok, I removed the fprintf statements, but I still have the same result. It still bypasses the EINPROGRESS error despite truss output indicating an EINPROGRESS error:                                                             
`3699/24:        so_socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP, 0, SOV_DEFAULT) = 7
3699/2:         connect(6, 0xFE01F854, 16, SOV_DEFAULT)         Err#150 EINPROGRESS
3699/24:        getsockname(0, 0xB611DAE4, 0xB611DB04, SOV_DEFAULT) Err#95 ENOTSOCK`

Comment: @user9608801 Then something else is wrong.  But without a complete example that can be used to duplicate your problem, it's impossible to tell. The odds that the problem is in Solaris 11 and not in your code are very, very low.  I'd look first for someone doing something dumb like redefining `errno` (doing *anything* to a system's definition of the `errno` macro results in undefined behavior...).  You can also just preprocess your code instead of compiling it all the way, just to see if there are some macros screwing things up.