# Obtain the native value of errno from Java in macOS

Tags: java, macos, native, errno, project-panama

I'm porting my JNA-based library to "pure" Java using the Foreign Function and Memory API ([JEP 424](https://openjdk.org/jeps/424)) in JDK 19.

I've successfully implemented the `sysctl()` function and am fetching values using:

```java
public static MethodHandle sysctl = Linker.nativeLinker().downcallHandle(
        SYSTEM_LIBRARY.lookup("sysctl").orElseThrow(), FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,
                ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS,
                ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG));
```

In the process of debugging before getting this working, I was occasionally getting a -1 return value:

> Upon successful completion, the value 0 is returned; otherwise the value -1 is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.

In JNA, this is easily obtainable using `Native.getLastError()`.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252588/1161484) shows how I could write code in JNI to fetch it, but the whole point of JEP 424 is to remove the need for JNA or JNI.

The Windows API has a helpful [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) function that can be mapped, as demonstrated in [this test in the JDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/test/jdk/com/sun/jdi/JdbLastErrorTest.java)

However, I was unable to find any native function on macOS that I could map to return `errno`.  The closest I have found is `perror()` which prints the error to STDERR:

```java
public static MethodHandle perror = Linker.nativeLinker()
        .downcallHandle(SYSTEM_LIBRARY.lookup("perror").orElseThrow(),
                FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS));
```

While output to STDERR was helpful in the near term, I'd like to use this value for exception handling/error messages.

This seems a common enough use case that there should be a method in the JDK for it, but I can't find it.

Any ideas other than temporarily redirecting STDERR into a string I can parse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to a mac to test this, but if this source is accurate: https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.41.2/bsd/sys/errno.h.auto.html

Then `errno` is a macro defined like so:

```
__BEGIN_DECLS
extern int * __error(void);
#define errno (*__error())
__END_DECLS
```

It's a call to a function that returns an `int*` that points to the `errno` value.

So, to access it from Java this should work:

```
static final MethodHandle __error = Linker.nativeLinker()
    .downcallHandle(SYSTEM_LIBRARY.lookup("__error").orElseThrow(),
            FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.ADDRESS));

static int errno() {
    try {
        MemoryAddress addr = (MemoryAddress) __error.invokeExact();
        return addr.get(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, 0);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
}
```

---

Be aware that at the moment (JDK 19) this is not a 100% reliable way to access `errno`, since the VM might block somewhere and override `errno` with its own system calls before the value can be read.

We've been discussing ways to make it more reliable to access `errno` and other thread-locals that the VM can overwrite. At the same time, that should also make it much easier to access the value.

Comment: This works!  Bonus points for the code suggestion for the wrapper method!

Answer (score 1):

There is a recommended alternative for JDK 21+, that is mentioned in the documentation of the [Linker class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/Linker.Option.html#captureCallState(java.lang.String...)):

```java
try (var confinedArena = Arena.ofConfined()) {

    // SYSTEM_LIBRARY doesn't exist anymore
    Function<String, MemorySegment> lookup = symbol ->
            Linker.nativeLinker().defaultLookup().find(symbol)
                    .or(() -> SymbolLookup.loaderLookup().find(symbol)).orElseThrow();

    // declare the errno as state to be captured, directly after the downcall without any interence of the
    // JVM runtime
    StructLayout capturedStateLayout = Linker.Option.captureStateLayout();
    VarHandle errnoHandle = capturedStateLayout.varHandle(MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("errno"));
    Linker.Option ccs = Linker.Option.captureCallState("errno");

    MethodHandle sysctl = Linker.nativeLinker().downcallHandle(
            lookup.apply("sysctl"), FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,
                    ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS,
                    ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG), ccs);

    MemorySegment capturedState = confinedArena.allocate(capturedStateLayout);
    try {
        int result = (int) sysctl.invoke(capturedState, ...);
        int errno = (int) errnoHandle.get(capturedState);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

To then get the error String, you can call the strerror function:

```java
String errnoString(int errno){
    AddressLayout POINTER = ValueLayout.ADDRESS.withTargetLayout(MemoryLayout.sequenceLayout(JAVA_BYTE));
    MethodHandle strerror = Linker.nativeLinker()
            .downcallHandle(lookup("strerror"),
                    FunctionDescriptor.of(POINTER, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT));
    try {
        MemorySegment str = (MemorySegment) strerror.invokeExact(errno);
        System.out.println(str);
        return str.getUtf8String(0);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
}
```

Edit: I wrote a blog post on the topic, you can read it at https://mostlynerdless.de/blog/2023/12/11/from-c-to-java-code-using-panama/

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the function you looked for is called `strerror`, which can map error codes(`errno`) to strings.

Based on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/intro.2.html). Error messages are set in the `errno` variable:

> When a system call detects an error, it returns an integer value indicat-ing indicating
> ing failure (usually -1) and sets the variable errno accordingly.  <This
> allows interpretation of the failure on receiving a -1 and to take action
> accordingly.> Successful calls never set errno; once set, it remains
> until another error occurs.  It should only be examined after an error.

```
#include <string.h> //header for strerror
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/errno.h> //Header for error enumerations.

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  //taking "EPERM" as an errno example
  int eperm = EPERM;

  char * errStr = strerror(eperm);

  printf("%s\n", errStr);//prints 'Operation not permitted'

  return 0;
}
```

So try `strerror` to convert `errno` to error message string

Comment: The problem with strerror is that it requires having errno to start with!